# How to Add a default Value for a Query Parameter and a drop down value for Query Param in WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am publishing a API in WSO2 API Manager publisher and there are two parameters where both are of string type but for one i need a default value and the other parameter i need to add drop down values.

Can you please help me on how to Add a default Value for a Query Parameter and a drop down value for Query Param in WSO2 API Manager.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Publisher UI does not support adding these. One thing you can do is to create the API using the OpenAPI file. Sample can be found below.

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Sample API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /fruit:
    get:
      summary: Get Fruit Information
      parameters:
        - name: type
          in: query
          description: Type of fruit
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
            default: Apple
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              example:
                message: "Fetching fruit information"

  /food:
    get:
      summary: Get Food Information
      parameters:
        - name: category
          in: query
          description: Category of food
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
            enum:
              - fruits
              - vegetables
            default: fruits
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          content:
            application/json:
              example:
                message: "Fetching food information"
```